# select a number of records that are not present in another SELECT resource

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tables, one is full of questions done to the users, the other is full of all the questions to do to all users, i would like to select the question, with the higher id (so it's new) that is not been sent to a given user... what i mean:

the first table has 3 fields :
     `id`,`questionid`,`userid` and its name is `userQuestions`

the otehr table is called `questions` and has 2 fields:

```
`qid` and `qText`
```

of course `qid` = `quesionid`

for a given `userid` how can i select all those questions not presented to `userid` ?

lets assume i have :

```
`qid` = 1 , `qtext` = 'qtext1'
`qid` = 2 , `qtext` = 'qtext2'
`qid` = 3 , `qtext` = 'qtext3'
```

and on the other table:

`id` = 1, `questionid` = 1, `userid` = 90

so this hypothetical SELECT should return
`qid` = 2
`qid` = 3

i hope i've been clear in the explanation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE qid NOT IN(SELECT questionid FROM userQuestions WHERE userid = 90);
```

Is trivial and simple

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT Q.qid
FROM questions Q
 LEFT JOIN userQuestions U
   ON Q.qid = U.questionid
 WHERE Q.userid = <user ID>
     AND U.id IS NULL
```